# Is it possible to send the user to the system settings?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

If I want to send a user to the facebook settings page under "system preferences" from within my app, what is the best possible way to do that, if it is indeed possible:

[image]

A case where this is useful would be if a user is trying to use an app's SSO capabilities to register for something using their facebook account. They click to register using facebook, but no facebook account is configured on the iPhone. It would be useful to then display a UIAlertView explaining that there is no facebook account configured, and then send the user to the settings page for facebook.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, Its not possible.

There is no way to launch device default "Settings" app from within your app. All you can do is give user some instructions of how to go about and change certain settings by themselves. You can do this as either a pop-up alert message or some sort of tutorial with screenshots built in your app.